# How wide is the node.js console?

Tags: node.js, console

In node.js, how do I get the current width of the console window and/or buffer?

The analog in .net is [Console.BufferWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.bufferwidth.aspx) and/or [Console.WindowWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.windowwidth.aspx).

I want to exercise more control over my line wrapping.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Looks like the current best way is this property:

```
process.stdout.columns
```

And for height (rows):

```
process.stdout.rows
```

Also note that there is a "resize" event, which might come in handy:

```
process.stdout.on('resize', function() {
  console.log('screen size has changed!');
  console.log(process.stdout.columns + 'x' + process.stdout.rows);
});
```

Documentation here:
http://nodejs.org/api/tty.html#tty_tty

Comment: In windows, [it's actually `Screen Buffer Size`](http://i.imgur.com/hztJGq3.png), not current console width.

Answer (score 17):

```
if (process.stdout.isTTY) {
  console.log("The console size is:", process.stdout.getWindowSize());
} else {
  console.log("stdout is not a console");
}
```

Comment: Is getWindowSize() cross-platform compatible?

Comment: @netpoetica  - yes `getWindowSize()` is platform compatible