# How can I determine the terminal width when piped (to a pager like less?)

Tags: node.js, terminal, pipe, posix

If my program is being piped to another program at the command-line, is there any way for me to still determine the width thereof?

I'm working in Node, if that's relevant, although any general POSIX solution is welcome (I can figure out how to port it to my environment myself.) Currently, I can use `process.stdout.columns` in Node; but that's linked to the `process.stdout`, which in this case is piped.

Comment: Check if environment variables `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` exist.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, POSIX does not define the C `ioctl` call used for getting the window size (see [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html)).  But the `TIOCGWINSZ` call (or similar `TIOCGSIZE`) is widely available.  Node probably relies on that in its checks.

This package checks the width for the standard output and failing that, checks the standard error: [window-size](https://www.npmjs.com/package/window-size) (see [source code](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/window-size/blob/master/index.js)).

A similar question was asked before in *[How wide is the node.js console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956386/how-wide-is-the-node-js-console)*

Comment: Finally got time to come back and check this. Unfortunately, `tty.getWindowSize` doesn't exist in my Node; and `.getWindowSize` doesn't exist when invoked inside of a pager. Meanwhile, `process.stdout.columns` is of course undefined, as it's tied to a pipe. So, that package's approach is a no-go. /=

Comment: Maybe there's something I could do with `TIOCGWINSZ` or `TIOCGSIZE` directly? Are *those* even defined when piped? I guess I'd have to write a C extension. Hrm.