# NodeJS simple horizontal line on console.log

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-modules, horizontal-line

I'm making a simple Node JS app.
It logs a lots of informations on console. I would like to know if it's possible to add a horizontal lines in Node JS command line without using any extra packages or dependencies. 
If command prompt supports HTML elements, then I could use something like `console.log("<hr>");` for adding a horizontal line but it does not support HTML.

Is there any way ?

Comment: You could do something like `console.log('--------------------------')`. If you want to fill the complete width of the terminal window, then you need an additional library.

Comment: Oh! No other idea ?

Comment: You can ask node for the current width of the terminal, but if the user resized the window then the horizontal lines that have already been printed won't be updated, so they will be either to short or to long.

Comment: [Get width of terminal in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335637/get-width-of-terminal-in-node-js) and [How wide is the node.js console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956386/how-wide-is-the-node-js-console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console does not support rendering HTML elements.

That does not prevent you from making a custom line however!

```
const lineBreak = '----------------------'
console.log(lineBreak)
```

Of course, customize the linebreak however you'd like:

```
______ //Underscores!
-----  //Hyphens!
====== //Equals!
```

For grouping related data, refer to the docs here: [console reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference)

Example:

```
function name(obj) {
  console.group('name');
  console.log('first: ', obj.first);
  console.log('middle: ', obj.middle);
  console.log('last: ', obj.last);
  console.groupEnd();
}

name({"first":"Wile","middle":"E","last":"Coyote"});
```

Will output grouped data to the console, visually giving it a line break & arrow to collapse the group. I think this would work well for your use case.

Comment: But for making it fit to screen, I have to use an other package.

Comment: Do you any library that can count console width and add only enough `-` characters ?

Comment: I don't know of any way to get the width of the console without another package. However, you can use console.group() to group related messages - and it adds a linebreak visually, as well as a "collapse" arrow.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: I added a link to the docs and an example of console.group() in my answer. Good luck!

Comment: No horizontal lines are seen in console 

Comment: console.group('Group name');
  console.log('data ')
  console.groupEnd();

Visually has a line break for me - paste the code into your chrome console - does it work?

Comment: Tried `console.group('name'); console.log('hi');  console.groupEnd();` but it isn't working. I giving it up. 

Comment: Make sure when you enter them into the console you have each statement on it's own line. You also can try using a table.

console.table([[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]);

Good luck!

Comment: No problem. Upvote/accept the answer if you found it helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: That answer is true. So,        

Answer (score 18):

To create the string for the horizontal line:

```
const line = '-'.repeat(process.stdout.columns)
```

`.repeat()` method repeats the string.

`process.stdout.columns` returns the number of columns.

To use it:

```
console.log(line)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide more information about why your solution answers the original question.

Comment: I think it is kind of self explanatory, don't you?
But maybe it could show the console log command along with the answer like:
`console.log('_'.repeat(process.stdout.columns));`

Answer (score 2):

Working off on the same vane as @sergey above:

If your output has a header of a determinable length you can use the `.length` method.

```js
const header="This is my header";
console.log(header);
console.log('-'.repeat(header.length);
```